# Passing model to Backbone View in object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm not sure this is possible, but I would like to pass parameters to functions in an object literal.

Here is my object:

```
var object_literal = {
    "thing" : new APP.SomeView({ model : model_to_pass, secondPart : static_model})
};
```

Then I wanted to loop though a collection, grab a reference

```
someCollection.each(function(things) {
    //will equal "thing"
    var x = things.get("reference");

    //Then do something like this (which obviously won't work)
    layout.someRegion.show(object_literal[x](model_to_pass))
}
```

As you can see, the 'thing' is a function (in this case a backbone view). I would like to pass 'thing' a parameter ('model_to_pass'). How can this be done?

If it makes it easier, I'm using backbone, underscore and jquery, if they offer better solutions.

Comment: `thing` is not a function here, but an instance of the APP.SomeView class (an object).

Comment: That's true. Is this still possible? I'll change the title of the question to be more accurate, I thought it may have been related

Comment: I'm still quite confused about what you want to do here. Is your goal to have several instances of `object_literal` (this can't be done)?

Comment: If `model_to_pass` and `static_model` are variables in scope then you're already passing them to `new APP.SomeView()` as properties of its object literal argument.

Comment: I want to have one 'object literal' that holds a bunch of views with parameters for their models. That way, whenever I want to call a view, I can reach into the object, pass a model and create a view. Does this make sense?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yeah, I see that's the issue. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @streetlight Oh. Well you just have to make a copy of them before passing them to the constructor.

Comment: @Loamhoof is there anyway you can post an example of doing something like this? I'm sorry, I'm just a bit lost with this issue!

Comment: @Loamhoof you're awesome. Thank you for giving answers to two of my questions in a row!

Comment: I think the issue here was that I wanted to define this before I called the views (I'm running an each loop through a collection and want to reference this object for their views), but I didn't want to redefine it each time for speed issues

Comment: Ok so you're defining a collection, creating an object (an array?) to store the views, then looping through the collection to store the views? And you're worried that because you're looping, the variables you're using change values and the references inside your views will be wrong?

Comment: The object_literal was to better organize the views (each object in the collection will have a reference a view), but I think it might just be easier to do a if/else or case statement in the each loop than work with this object.

Comment: Thank you for helping me navigate this issue, @Loamhoof. You're great!

Comment: @streetlight I think it's gonna be case specific, could you provide the code as it will be? (I still don't think there should be a problem here x))

Comment: @Loamhoof - I went and edited my questions to be more specific, and provided the solution I was talking about in the answer. Please edit or comment if you think there's an improvement that can be made! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Let's chat a bit more if you want, I'm still quite interested and have 2 or 3 more details to clear my mind ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28250/discussion-between-loamhoof-and-streetlight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided this was a bit over-engineering for the solution, and using conditionals would be the best approach.

```
someCollection.each(function(things) {
    //will equal "thing"
    var x = things.get("reference");

    if (x === "thing") {
        new APP.SomeView({ model : model_to_pass, secondPart : static_model}
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help!